# Python dictionaries matrix "representation"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary dict in Python. 
Imagine this simple example. Dict:

```
bin1:{apple,apple,cherry,cherry,cherry,banana,banana,avocado}
bin2:{cucumber,cucumber,cucumber,cucumber,apple}
bin3:{cherry,cherry,banana,banana}
```

I want to calculate and store this (in any representation, I just can't come up with data structure):

[image]

Rows represent all keys, columns represent all available distinct fruits in all dictionary values

Numbers mean this: for each key, we calculate number of times fruit appears for that key divided by number of times other particular fruit appears the most for that key.

Ex: for bin1: cherry appears the most (3), so apples would be 2/3 (apples appear 2 times divided by cherry appears 3 times) and so on.

Maybe we can create something like dictionary inside dictionary:

```
bin1:{apple:2/3,banana:2/3,cherry:1,cucumber:0,avocado:1/3}
bin2:{apple:1/4,banana:0,cherry:0,cucumber:1,avocado:0}
bin3:{apple:0,banana:1,cherry:1,cucumber:0,avocado:0}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/), [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an operation on a list, as you just work on each row on its own. So

```
row1 = ["apple", "apple", "cherry", "cherry", "cherry", "banana", "banana", "avocado"]
import collections
row1count = collections.Counter(row1)
max_per_row = max(row1count.values())  # for python2: wrap with float()
{x: y/max_per_row for (x, y) in row1count.items()}
```

Result is

> {'apple': 0.6666666666666666, 'cherry': 1.0, 'banana': 0.6666666666666666, 'avocado': 0.3333333333333333}

This uses `collections.Counter` to compute the number of occurrences of each item. It then determines the maximum value, and divides by it in a dict comprehension.